# Keeping a center point when scene is moving

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am new to swift and making a game where the SKCamera is moving on the scene but I wanna keep the center of the scene updated when skcamera moves along. Just wondering what can I use.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean "keep the center of the scene updated when skcamera moves along"  If you are using a camera, the camera is always the the center of the screen,  and the entire scene is always updating.  I am going to take a stab in the dark here and say you are not setting `scene.camera = SKCameraNode`.  Other than this,  you will need to clarify what you are asking for.

Use this to set the camera to the ball after it passes a certain point:

`camera.y = ball.position.y > scene.height/2 ? ball.position.y : scene.height / 2`

Comment: okay so my problem is My game is a little bit like color switch so a ball goes up and the camera goes up if the balls goes over a certain Y point but after my first statement 

if ball.position.y > self.frame.midY well the camera goes up but wont stop because the mid of the screen wont update

Comment: I never played color switch, but i think i understand you.  You need to show code, becAuse you need to set camera y = ball position y when ball y passes a certain theshold

Comment: `camera.y = ball.position.y > scene.height/2 ? ball.position.y : scene.height / 2`

Comment: yeh replacing the camera y to ball y after a certain point was what i was looking for thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `SKSpriteNode` as child of your camera node, and you set it to the center of the **camera node**, it will stay at the center of the screen, even when the camera moves.